# Confusion over Sockets and Ports

Tags: sockets, port

I am trying to write a programme that will 'listen' to application that is running on a port over TCP/IP.

When I point my browser to localhost:30003 , I get the output stream from the application printed to the screen. It would appear that the browser successfully 'listens' to the port.

What is happening here? Is my browser polling the application or is the application pushing tcp data which the browser picks up?

I am not sure whether to get this data I need to create a client or server instance.

Comment: It's a client instance you need (to connect on port 30003).

Comment: Removed the `[java]` tag, it's not really relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the best ways to find out what is actually happening is to fire up Wireshark and follow the tcp stream.

http://www.wireshark.org/

Alternately, you can use something like TCP mon if you only care about the text, and none of the networking details.

http://ws.apache.org/commons/tcpmon/download.cgi

Based on the limited information in your question, the most likely thing is that the browser makes the tcp connection, and you send back a malformed response. The brower assumes you are a broken site, and does it's best to adjust. If you aren't sending the correct http header, it dosn't know what else to do so it *probably* just puts the text on the screen.

Best way to know the details is with wireshark or tcpmon

Answer (score 0):

Pointing the browser to localhost:30003 will cause it the open the connection to port 30003 on the localhost and sent the string "GET /" to request a web page from what is thinks is a web host. Whatever text is sent by your app upon receiving a connection is simply displayed by the web browser as if it had received the contents of a text file on a web server.

Answer (score 0):

when you write "`localhost:30003`" in your browser a connection is established to some program that listens to the port 30003 on your computer. The prefix in the URL, (default HTTP) determines the protocol used by server and client, in this case the browser is the client connecting to your PC, the server.

If you want to do the same with your program you can set up a socket connection to your localhost using the same port 30003. Your program then becomes the client. Depending on the program (which you don't mention anything about) you may have more protocol options and would need to handle the protocol in your program.

An alternative is to use `telnet` to connect to your program but it depends on available protocols.